# Ajax returns the whole page again

Tags: ajax

I am trying to add Ajax on a form having a button so that when the button is clicked the form is submitted but should not reload.

Current it is rendering the whole page again below the existing page.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var form = $('#contact_us'); // contact form
    var submit = $('button');  // submit button
    var alert = $('#form-status'); // alert div for show alert message

    // form submit event
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

        $.ajax({
            url: '/contact-us', // form action url
            type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
            dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
            data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert.fadeOut();
                submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your page at /contact-us doesn't send you formatted data(eg. JSON) and you don't parse it, you will get whole page rendered. Why? Because of:

```
alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
```

It simply fades in whole page. Data is everything you get from /contact-us. To fix it, you have to delete line with appending whole page, so your success code should look like this:

```
success: function(data) {
                form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
            },
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend using alert as variable name. This name is already used.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, It helped. Now can you just help me with how can i show a success message once the page is reloaded? I am doing something like this in the end


$('#form-status').text('SUCCESS');

Comment: Once the page is RELOADED you could use PHP's `if($_POST && $_POST['name'])` etc. If you mean once AJAX request is completed you have to add logic to success callback, but there is no point in appending data as long as it's complete page. However, you could create another php file, post to new file and it may return JSON formatted message depending on validation logic in PHP, eg. `{ 'success': true, 'error': '' }` - when everything went good and `{ 'success' : false, 'error': 'Error #1: Message'` } - when there's an error, then, you parse it in ajax function and check using `if(data.success)`.